# How to show form2 in front and form1 in second using winforms?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I wants to show form2(Filter Form) first. Actually I am calling form2 from Form1(Report Test Form) page load. But It appears Form2 in back position and Form1 in First position.

**Code**

```
private void ReportTestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportFilterForm report = new ReportFilterForm();
    report.Show();
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

**Note**

I don't want to hide Form 1

Comment: _report.Show(this);_

Comment: @Steve thank you steve. It's working. But can you tell me how `this` works here

Comment: [This explain the Owner property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) in Winforms. Strangely it is best explained in the WPF documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use *TopMost* Property:

```
private void ReportTestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportFilterForm report = new ReportFilterForm();
    report.TopMost = true;

    report.Show();

}
```

Comment: And what happens if another application set the TopMost property for itself?. Who wins?

Comment: the last one always wins.

Answer (score 0):

ShowDialog will force Form2 to be close to be able to return to Form1

```
report.ShowDialog();
```